# How to register routes in a different function with actix-web?

Tags: rust, actix-web

I'm creating an [actix-web](https://crates.io/crates/actix-web) application and I would like to register routes in a separate function. However, I cannot write a function that takes and returns `App::new()` since `AppEntry` is private:

```rust
use actix_web::{web, App, HttpResponse, HttpServer, Responder};

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    HttpServer::new(|| {
        let app = App::new();
        register_routes(&app)
    })
        .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?
        .run()
        .await
}

fn register_routes(app: App<AppEntry>) -> App<AppEntry> {
    App::new()
        .route("/hey", web::get().to(hello))
}

async fn hello() -> impl Responder {
    HttpResponse::Ok().body("Hey there!")
}
```

```
error[E0412]: cannot find type `AppEntry` in this scope
  --> src/main.rs:14:29
   |
14 | fn register_routes(app: App<AppEntry>) -> App<AppEntry> {
   |                   -         ^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
   |                   |
   |                   help: you might be missing a type parameter: `<AppEntry>`
```

How should I write the `register_routes` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `App::configure` for that, avoiding the need to pass an `App<AppEntry>` directly, like they show in [this example](https://actix.rs/docs/application/#configure).

By the way, in your `register_routes` function, you just create another, new `App`, you don't actually use the one that you pass in.